# Div style inheritance issue

Tags: css, html, opacity

I'm trying to embed one DIV inside another without it inheriting the opacity style of the wrapper DIV.

Style Code :

```
#outer {
background-color: #000;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
z-index: 0;
opacity: 1;
}

#inner {
background-color: #000;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few different solutions but none have worked as yet.

Comment: Do the divs need to be nested? I've always solved this problem by using absolute positioning to place an opaque div on top of a transparent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3s [`rgba`](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) property to solve that problem (Works for colors).

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
```

If you want to support older browser which do not support CSS3 or `rgba` property (or when you have images in background), here are links to other possible solutions:

- [Non-Transparent Elements Inside Transparent Elements](http://css-tricks.com/384-non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/)
- [CSS Background Transparency Without Affecting Child Elements, Through RGBa And Filters](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)

Other cross-browser solution is to use semi-transparent ***PNGs*** for your divs.

Comment: Definate answer if you only want color. +1

Comment: Yeah that's the only solution really! This answer says it all

Comment: I'll give the rgba a try but probably fall back on just using images. Seems dumb that it just doesn't "work".

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can do that man.

Two solutions, if it's just the background color, you could:

1. Use a transparent .png image
2. use rgba. E.g, for black with 60% transparency: `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);`

Comment: This works perfectly but it's limited by the browsers that supports CSS3. I tried it in IE8 and it didn't work correctly. Looks like my option will be the transparent image.

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible. The opacity will be applied to everything within.  [See the spec for more information](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency).